# Python. Матрицы

Tags: python

Есть матрица NxN.

Необходимо заполнить единицами часть матрицы от главной диагонали до верхнего правого угла, но не трогать элементы, которые лежат на левой половине матрицы. Если N нечетное, в центральном столбце тоже должны быть единицы.

Как нужно сделать исключение для левой половины?

```
import random
N = int(input("Разряд: "))
matrix = [[random.randrange(-10,10) for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)]
print("Начальная матрица: ",matrix)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if j > i:
            matrix[i][j] = 1

print("Конечная матрица: ",matrix)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

основной цикл можно сделать таким образом, чтобы идти от главной диагонали для нечетных и на один шаг позже для четных

```
add = (N+1) % 2
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+add,N):
        matrix[i][j] = 1
```

---

весь код

```
import random
from pprint import pprint

N = int(input("Разряд: "))
matrix = [[random.randrange(0,9) for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)]
print("Начальная матрица: ")
pprint(matrix)
add = (N+1) % 2
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+add,N):
        matrix[i][j] = 1
print("Конечная матрица: ")
pprint(matrix)
```

вот, что получается в одном случае

```
Разряд: 3
Начальная матрица: 
[[7, 4, 3], [7, 5, 3], [3, 5, 5]]
Конечная матрица: 
[[1, 1, 1], [7, 1, 1], [3, 5, 1]]
```

и во втором

```
Разряд: 4
Начальная матрица: 
[[8, 5, 7, 5], [6, 0, 8, 1], [8, 7, 4, 0], [8, 4, 6, 6]]
Конечная матрица: 
[[8, 1, 1, 1], [6, 0, 1, 1], [8, 7, 4, 1], [8, 4, 6, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант

```
import random

N = int(input("Разряд: "))
matrix = [[random.randrange(-10,10) for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)]

print("Начальная матрица: ")
for row in matrix:
    for el in row:
        print(f'{el:3}', end=' ')
    print()
    
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(max(N>>1, i), N):
        matrix[i][j] = 1
            
print("Конечная матрица: ")
for row in matrix:
    for el in row:
        print(f'{el:3}', end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал таким способом, что изменил range, до это ввёл переменную half = (N/2)
Если будут другие идеи - будет очень интересно узнать
Мой код получился таким:

```
import random
N = int(input("Разряд: "))
matrix = [[random.randrange(-10,10) for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)]
print("Начальная матрица: ",matrix)
half = int(N/2)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(half,N):
        if j > i:
            matrix[i][j] = 1
print("Конечная матрица: ",matrix)
```

Comment: вы его пробовали запускать ? он неверно работает